# How to configure a mercurial server accessed using a single ssh account to pick usernames based on the key being used?

Tags: mercurial

I so have several mercurial servers and people are pushing changes using a single user `hg` and using, only, ssh public key authentication, each of them having it's own key.

**How can I configure the server so it will pick the username for push based on the public key being used?**

Is it possible? If not, why and what alternatives so I do not have to configure the username in `.hgrc` on each account * machine where I connect to.

Also, think about other use case: you have an hg repository cloned by root on a machine and two different people are connecting this machine (as root), making changes and trying to commit and push the changes.

These two are using the same account but they are connected using different ssh keys, so you would want to see who did this. Currently these will appear as the user configured in .hgrc

Answer (score 2):

The "username used for push", i.e., the username and password used for *authentication* when pushing has **nothing** to do with the username shown by `hg log`.

When you make a **commit**, Mercurial records the name of the user running `hg commit`. This is typically configured in `~/.hgrc` for that user. This information is part of the changeset and cannot be changed later.

For your particular use case where several different admins run `hg commit` while being logged in as `root`, I can suggest *not* to configure a username in `~/.hgrc`. Modern Mercurial will then abort when you commit. It is of course very annoying to use `hg commit -u` every time, so it is lucky that you can set the username by configuring the `HGUSER` environment variable. That way you configure the username on a per-session basis without using a persistent configuration.

To get `HGUSER` passed when you do ssh, see [Can I forward env variables over ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409951/can-i-forward-env-variables-over-ssh)

When I used this scheme I just found the right username in the command line history by pressing Ctrl-r and searching for `HGUSER`. You could probably also setup something in the shell startup script where you look at the key with `ssh-add -L` and set the right username based on that.

Comment: Still, I do not see this as a solution as me and others do use the same computer for committing to private or public repositories, where the username would be different.