# Inherit environment variable in ssh session?

Tags: linux, ssh

I need to deal with a lot of remote machines, and each machine shares a global environment variable (
like CONTROLLER_IP). When I try to ssh to the remote machine, I would like to set the CONTROLLER_IP 
according to current localhost setting. is there any way to make it happen?

Example:

In localhost host, I set ofc1=192.168.0.1, and ofc2=192.168.1.1
and I need to ssh to ofs1, ofs2.
I would like to do something like:

```
CONTROLLER_IP=$ofc1 ssh root@ofs1; CONTROLLER_IP=$ofc2 ssh root@ofs2
```

then I will get the CONTROLLER_IP setting in each ssh session.
 (the code shown above does not work...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I forward env variables over ssh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409951/can-i-forward-env-variables-over-ssh)

Comment: The `$ofc1` is suspicious. Are you sure you don't just mean `CONTROLLER_IP=ofc1` ?

Comment: no, ofc1 is just another env var in my localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/etc/sshd_config` on the server you can define the list of accepted environment variables using the `AcceptEnv` setting, and then you can send environment variables like this:

```
CONTROLLER_IP=$ofc1 ssh -o SendEnv=CONTROLLER_IP root@ofs1
```

But this seems a bit overkill for your purposes.

The alternative is to pass the variables in the remote command, like this:

```
ssh root@ofs1 "CONTROLLER_IP=$ofc1 somecmd"
```

Or if you run multiple remote commands then like this:

```
ssh root@ofs1 "export CONTROLLER_IP=$ofc1; cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; ..."
```

If you need to quote the value of the variable, you can do like this:

```
ssh root@ofs1 "CONTROLLER_IP='$ofc1' somecmd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 ssh root@ofs1 "env CONTROLLER_IP=$ofc1 somescript"
```

(assuming `$ofc1` is evaluated to some IP address like `12.234.56.178` without spaces or naughty characters)

or perhaps

```
 ssh root@ofs1 "env CONTROLLER_IP='$ofc1' somescript"
```

if `$ofc1` could contain spaces or naughty characters

where `somescript` is a script on the remote machine `ofs1`; if you want an interactive shell try

```
 ssh root@ofs1 "env CONTROLLER_IP='$ofc1' /bin/bash"
```

At last, `ssh` is usually setting some environment variables (on the remote machine), notably the `SSH_CONNECTION` one. You could use it on the remote machine. Its third field is the IP address of the origin host (the one on which you do the `ssh` ...). So perhaps the `.bashrc` on the remote host might contain

```
 if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]; then
   export CONTROLLER_IP=$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION|cut -f3 -d' ')
 fi
```

better yet, replace the `CONTROLLER_IP` occurrences in your remote scripts with something using `SSH_CONNECTION`

Comment: I want to send the setting of env var and still able to log into the ssh session. Your code just runs some command and exits ssh.