# How can I get git to show colored output during hook output?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm currently using `git` to deploy a project, and I was wondering how I could get the output of tools like `npm` and `gulp` to be in color in the same that they are when using those tools locally?

For example

[image]

vs

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: either force colored output for each tool used in git hooks on the remote side or forcibly set `TERM` environment variable (again, on the remote side). Use `export TERM=xterm` (or `export TERM=xterm-color`) somewhere in the beginning of each hook script.

The long answer: by default unix tools like `npm` or `git` itself generate colored output (i.e. output with extra escape-sequences which change color accordingly) only if these tools can detect that terminal in which they operate is capable to change colors. Terminal capabilities is defined via environment variable `TERM`. Ordinary, interactive SSH sessions can transfer `TERM` value to a remote side (see [Can I forward env variables over ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409951/can-i-forward-env-variables-over-ssh)) but non-interactive sessions usually don't do this, non-interactive sessions may operate in TTY-less mode. You can force usage of color for a particular tool (e.g. [npm via config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#color)) or configure TERM environment variable properly.

Answer (score 2):

On your remote server

type in

```
git config --global color.ui auto
```

That should give you color

Answer (score 1):

For those using nodejs based projects, it seems colored output issues with git hooks are a consequence of git running hooks without "tty" support by default.

This cause some tools to consider the terminal does not supports colors.

For instance, as discussed here https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/693

If you are using node based tools, you may fix your issue by adding `export FORCE_COLOR=1` in your hook script. This will fix all tools based on this library : https://www.npmjs.com/package/supports-color