# jenkins/docker with environment variables

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to use a docker machine in Jenkins, and have that machine have an environment variable (FOO) set.  I've successfully setup an image using a docker template in my jenkins configuration.  Meaning, that's probably not my problem spot.  The problem is that I cannot seem to get the environment variable to be available.  If I create a jenkins project that just tries to do "echo $FOO", all I get is a blank line.

My Dockerfile is based on ubuntu-14.04, and ends with:
`CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]`

Things that I've tried:

- In the jenkins configuration page, in the "docker template" section, I've added "FOO=1" to the "environment" field.  However, when I click "save", this change is not saved.
- Adding to the Dockerfile various ways to set FOO:

  - RUN echo "export FOO=1" >> /etc/profile
  - ENV FOO 1
  - RUN echo export FOO=1 >> ~/.bashrc
- [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).  This works, but requires you to check the checkbox in every single jenkins plan.  I'm hoping for a solution where I only have to do something once.

References:

- [Jenkins bug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30113).  You cannot set FOO in the Jenkins environment and expect it to be passed to the docker container.
- [Docker's advice](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/).  This page suggests (I think) adding the env variable to /etc/profile.  As I mentioned, this failed for me.
- [Passing env through ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409951/can-i-forward-env-variables-over-ssh).  This explains how you can modify an ssh call to pass env vars, but I don't know how to access that part of the command within jenkins.  (Note, it's fine to expose the variable on the command line.)
- [ssh set user env](https://superuser.com/questions/48783/how-can-i-pass-an-environment-variable-through-an-ssh-command).  This answer seemed a bit overkill, and I didn't test to see if it worked.  Presumably I would have the Dockerfile add .ssh/environment and I would have to enable PermitUserEnvironment.

Comment: Already tried to mount an --env-file to your jenkins container (when you start up your container?)

Answer (score 1):

I have Jenkins running in a docker container and I use it to run other containers. Jenkins connects to the containers to build and Android app via ssh, but the environment varaibles always got cleared by ssh.
I solved the problem by writing the environment vars to /etc/environment, and then they are automatically loaded on login.
This is the last steps of my dockerfile:

```
RUN env | grep _ >> /etc/environment

EXPOSE 22

USER jenkins

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Comment: I dont think this answer the question. Issue is when Jenkins logs in it wipes the environment variables out.