# Passing $PS1 over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I couldnt find answer to this althougth there are many similar questions.I wanted to change colour of my linux command prompt based on the remote host i have ssh to.Since bash environment variables are not preserved over ssh,so how could i do this.There are hundreds of server i login everyday.So changing /.bashrc of each remote host is not possible.is there a way i can pullout a script which can be called each time ssh is done.Can someone please give in detail of which file and how it should be edited.gnome,openssh etc are not supprted.

Comment: You could use something like `ssh host "PS1=$PS1 bash"`, but any configuration files on the remote end that configure `PS1` will almost certainly not check to see if `PS1` is already set.

Comment: See: [Can I forward env variables over ssh?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4409951/3776858)

Comment: But what I m looking for is a change in a conf file or something like that or some script which can be called everytime i ssh,without a change in d way I use SSH command...

Answer (score 1):

during ssh execution,a new login shell was executed.
during shell login the *rc files are not executed,only *profile was executed.

so place your code in */etc/profile* or *~/.bash_profile*.

Answer (score 0):

*"Since bash environment variables are not preserved over ssh..."*

man ssh

> ```
>  Additionally, ssh reads ~/.ssh/environment, and adds lines of the format
>      “VARNAME=value” to the environment if the file exists and users are
>      allowed to change their environment.  For more information, see the
>      PermitUserEnvironment option in sshd_config(5).
> ```

Comment: This only works if the server's configuration has enabled
PermitUserEnvironment , which is off by default.