# Jenkins how to pass GIT_BRANCH parameter in my remote shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

actually I need GIT_BRANCH parameter in my shell script under post build action and that script will run on my remote ssh machine I have echo GIT_BRANCH parameter but it is empty can anyone help how to I will pass my environment variable in my remote shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Branch Name=>" $GIT_BRANCH

if [ $GIT_BRANCH == 'origin/master' ] then   
   DOCKERFILE_NAME='Dockerfile.master'    docker build -f
   $DOCKERFILE_NAME -t master_image:v1 .
elif [ $GIT_BRANCH=='origin/development' ] then   
   DOCKERFILE_NAME='Dockerfile.development'    docker build -f
   $DOCKERFILE_NAME -t development_image:v1 .
else
   echo "branch cannot be handle"
fi

echo "DOCKERFILE NAME:"$DOCKERFILE_NAME
```

Comment: if you connect to the remote server via ssh, you can append some env variables as well - this needs some changes to the ssh server configuration. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409951/can-i-forward-env-variables-over-ssh

if you're using the native ssh you can do something like this then ssh user@host "GIT_BRANCH=${GIT_BRANCH}". Not tried yer, but could work.

Otherwise please update your question and give some more details about the build.

Answer (score 0):

As you know GIT_BRANCH is not set on your remote machine, you need to pass it as an parameter of the script. 
Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
GIT_BRANCH="$1"
echo "Branch Name=>" $GIT_BRANCH

if [ $GIT_BRANCH == 'origin/master' ] then   
   DOCKERFILE_NAME='Dockerfile.master'    docker build -f
   $DOCKERFILE_NAME -t master_image:v1 .
elif [ $GIT_BRANCH=='origin/development' ] then   
   DOCKERFILE_NAME='Dockerfile.development'    docker build -f
   $DOCKERFILE_NAME -t development_image:v1 .
else
   echo "branch cannot be handle"
fi

echo "DOCKERFILE NAME:"$DOCKERFILE_NAME
```

and run it like below

```
ssh ${remote_address} ${script_path} $GIT_BRANCH
```

for Ex, remote address is 10.0.0.1 and script path is /var/lib/test.sh,

```
ssh 10.0.0.1 /var/lib/test.sh $GIT_BRANCH
```